# List<string> passed in ViewBag gets with “System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]”

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a link to another controller and I want to pass a list of strings.

FirstController.cs

I have list of records in table with checkbox in each row, List of string values are selected by checking the checkbox.

```
public ActionResult Select(bool isChecked, String id)
{
    var selectList = (List<String>)HttpContext.Session["SelectList"] ?? new List<String>();
    if (isChecked && !selectList.Contains(id))
    {
        selectList.Add(id);
    }
    else if (!isChecked && selectList.Contains(id))
    {
        selectList.RemoveAll(s => s == id);
    }
    ViewBag.selectList = selectList;
    return Content("OK");
}
```

The list of string values i am passing to SecondController.cs using 'ViewBag'

```
public ActionResult AddSitesToUser(string returnUrl,string selectList, int userId = 0)
{
    ViewBag.selectList = selectList;
}
```

View:

```
(Html.BeginForm("AddSitesToUser", "User", new { returnUrl = ViewBag.returnUrl,selectList=((List<string>)ViewBag.selectList )})
```

In my FirstController.cs the list of ViewBag.selectList = selectList; created properly, but if i pass those list of strings to SecondController.cs instead of returning list of strings it gives me '"System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]"

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The argument for `selectList` in the `AddSitesToUser` is a string, so that's what you got.

Comment: I tried passing List<string>selectList but still same issue.

Comment: You cant assign a collection to a route parameter. You need to create inputs for each item in the collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your view Hidde the list of strings inside of the form how calls the SecondController

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Second", "Second", new { returnUrl = ViewBag.returnUrl }))
 {
if (ViewBag.StringList != null)
{
    foreach (string item in ViewBag.StringList)
    {
        @Html.Hidden("StringList", item);
    }

}
  <input type="submit" class="nar-btn nar-form-size75" value="Submit List" />
 }
```

then in your controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult Second(string returnUrl, List<string> StringList)
    {
        // you should be now able to access to your list
        return View();
    }
```